# Voltage across capacitor is shifted -20 VDC in PSPICE simulation

Tags: pspice

I tried to create a simple simulation in Orcad PSPICE. For some reasons, the measured AC voltage across the capacitor C is shifted -20 Vdc. Its value should vary in the range [-20V, +20V] as far as I'm concerned. Very appreciate if anyone can give me an idea of what's going on here. Thank you very much.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You either haven't simulated for long enough  - or RC is too large. Try simulating for 10 * RC (you may want to reduce R to less than 1G :-) Once you understand that, there may be fixes involving different initial conditions...

Comment: Thank Brian. The initial condition is Vc(t=0s)=0V. I did try to run over 10 * time constant but the result didn't change.

Comment: Then are you sure that is a current source?

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm modeling a practical AC sinusoidal current source (1 ideal current source // big resistor)

Answer (score 3):

The initial charge of the capacitor is 0. You then start sucking out current through the current source (it starts with the negative cycle). The voltage can only decrease. Eventually the current source goes positive, the capacitor will get some charge again, and its voltage will increase *back to the initial condition*, 0 volt. Then the cycle repeats.

Comment: Thank pipe. Intuitively, your explanation really makes sense. What I don't understand here is if I do the calculation, Vc(t) has no DC component. Am I missing something here? Thank you very much.

Comment: @dejoker Ok, I haven't done this in a long time, but is it possible that you calculate this using an integral, and the [constant of integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_integration) is in play? You just assume it's zero, when it can be any number.

Comment: @dejoker the issue is the reference point. BEcause the current source is tied to ground on one side it is not really an AC source the way you are thinking of one. The reference point you are calculating is based on a reference in the middle of the current source. Try using two identical 2A sources in series and put ground in between them.

Comment: @pipe No, I did the calculation using phasor (complex number) of the circuit parameters -_-

Comment: @pipe maybe you didn't do this in a long time, but you certainly did not forget how it works ;) I second your opinion.

Comment: @dejoker so what is the phasor of the current source, in your calculations?

Comment: Thank @VladimirCravero my calculation is as follows: i=4; Total impedance Z ~ Zc = -5j --> Vc = i*Z = -20j = 20sin(100Pi*t - Pi/2)    (My apology I haven't checked how to type formula here. Any quick link to guide is very much appreciated!!)

Comment: @Trevor Thanks for the answer. The reference point should not be the problem here. I tried as you suggested anyway to double check and the result is still the same.

Comment: @dejoker then you did not do it right. You need to measure the delta voltage across the cap with the double source. That should be centered at the new ground. Anyhow, this answer is correct, your math/method is wrong.

Comment: @Trevor very appreciate your answer. Could you do me a favor to setup the simulation and measurement as you described? I tried but failed so I'm afraid I missed something here. I really need to know what went wrong here. Thank you very much.

Comment: @dejoker ya I tried that yesterday.. for some reason spice did not like having two current sources in series like that. But that aside, your issue here is your math. This question is pretty much done. You should really start a new question and show your math so someone can see, and explain to you, where your math goes sideways.

Comment: @Trevor I showed my calculation in my previous answer (to Vladimir). Thank Trevor.